Sitecore SPEAK ItemTreeView items access
I've created Sitecore SPEAK v2 app with ItemTreeView component with a root of /sitecore in master DB.
When I use this app as a user which has access to /sitecore/Content items only (which is confirmed in Content Editor), I see all other items same way as admin user sees.
Is there a way to restrict ItemTreeView (actually Item Web API) to show only items accessible by current user?

Welcome to Stack-overflow. Please elaborate your question. We would like to see a sample code you have tried or an informative screenshot of the problem you are currently facing. So we can easily understand the context. Thank you.
